# Equivalent criteria query for named query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

My named query looks like this, thanks to [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914075/simple-hql-named-query-that-uses-a-inner-join/7914485#7914485)

```
@NamedQuery(
name="Cat.favourites", 
query="select c 
      from Usercat as uc 
      inner join uc.cat as c 
      where uc.isFavourtie = true 
      and uc.user = :user")
```

And the call to implement looks like this :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Cat.favourites");
query.setEntity("user", myCurrentUser);
return query.list();
```

What would be the equivalent criteria query that returns a list of cats ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JPA 2.0 Criteria:
(This is one of the many ways you can achieve this using JPA 2.0 Criteria api)

```
final CriteriaQuery<Cat> cq = getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Cat.class);
final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

final Root<Usercat> uc= cq.from(Usercat.class);

cq.select(uc.get("cat");

Predicate p = cb.equal(uc.get("favourtie", true);
p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(uc.get("user"), user));
cq.where(p);

final TypedQuery<Cat> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
return typedQuery.getResultList();
```