# JPA NamedQuery for OneToMany Relation

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, named-query

I am trying to create a `named-query` in my `orm.xml` but I am not sure how it works with the collection. I have created a query in `postgresql` which gives me the correct output. But I am not able to translate it to my `orm.xml`.

The `postgresql`query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.manufacturer, b.name, b.price, b.quantity, b.version, b.incentiveentity_id
from beverageentity b INNER JOIN customerorderentity_beverageentity c ON b.id = c.beverageentities_id
Group by b.id;
```

CustomerOrderEntity Class:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerOrderEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    private Date issueDate;

    private boolean existIncentive;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BeverageEntity> beverageEntities;
}
```

BeverageEntity Class:

```
@Entity
public class BeverageEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String manufacturer;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    @Version
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private IncentiveEntity incentiveEntity;
```

In my orm.xml I have written the query like this:

```
<named-query name="getAllOrders">
        <query>SELECT b.id, b.manufacturer, b.name, b.price, b.quantity, b.version, b.incentiveEntity.id
            from BeverageEntity b INNER JOIN CustomerOrderEntity.beverageEntities c ON b.id = c.id
            Group by b.id
        </query>
    </named-query>
```

But after compiling I am getting this exception:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT b.id, b.manufacturer, b.name, b.price, b.quantity, b.version, b.incentiveEntity.id
                        from BeverageEntity b INNER JOIN CustomerOrderEntity.beverageEntities c ON b.id = c.id
                        Group by b.id
                ].
[123, 159] The collection-valued path 'CustomerOrderEntity.beverageEntities' cannot be resolved to a valid association field.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Comment: did you check this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914075/simple-hql-named-query-that-uses-a-inner-join

Comment: Yes, I have checked this and many other answers too. I just want to get all the records which match `beverage id` with `customer entity` beverages list inside the a beverage id.